# Conexión Java con Oracle 7.3.4 u Oracle 8i

Tags: java, oracle

Buen día quiero compartir con ustedes esta solución que encontré, si han tenido problemas al conectar bases de datos **Oracle 7.3.x** u **Oracle 8i** la solución que me ha funcionado después de tanto buscar es usar **Classes12.zip** y **Classes111.zip** no Classes.jar y Classes11.jar sino las .zip, espero les pueda servir.

Saludos...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.